# terminal doesn't work: it doesn't start anymore. How to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

i'm noob on Ubuntu. I was updating Python from 3.5.2 to 3.6 when I understood terminal was not working anymore.

In this moment Ctrl + Alt + T is useless, also the esecutor on Applications doesn't work.

I found this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/114856/terminal-does-not-start-on-remote-desktop-how-to-fix-it

but I really do not know how to follow any instructions without terminal.

UPDATE:

**I fix it by switching back on Python 3.5.2. What about if I wonder to keep python updated?**

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use [pip & virtualenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) - don't mess with the system python. I think you should be able to install python3.6 with the `python3.6` & `python3.6-venv` package.